# IndexError: string index out of range "RLE"

Tags: python, compression, rle

when I input A15, it produces "IndexError: string index out of range" on line 7. what is the cause of my code error ?

```
Compress = input("Silahkan Input teks: ")
HasilDecompress =""

PKarakter =len(Compress)

for i in range (0, PKarakter ,2):
    JumPerulangan = int(Compress[i+1])
    for j in range (0, JumPerulangan): 
        HasilDecompress = HasilDecompress + Compress [i]

print ("Hasil Decompress Adalah = ", HasilDecompress)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decrease the `PKarakter` by 1 because you access `Compress[i+1]`. So that makes it out of range.

So you have to change:

```py
PKarakter = len(Compress)-1
```